# Cancel Kubuntu OS installation

Tags: kubuntu, uninstall, preinstallation

I am very, VERY new to Ubuntu and Linux as a whole. I was going to attempt to install Kubuntu and manually configure my partitions, but I was very confused on how to do it. So, at the Disk Setup page, I decided that it wouldn't be worth it and too risky.

I have an urgent question. Can I just click "back" on every step and then cancel it, and then boot into Windows? I didn't start the whole installation process yet, but I'm afraid I might screw something up.

I know this is a really stupid question, but if anyone could help, that would be extremely appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't write any of the partition changes until a couple of screens after that. It explicitly asks you if you want to write the changes to disk, so you would've seen it. You're free to just power off the computer, remove the Kubuntu installer, and reboot into Windows.

Hope you try it again sometime!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I also removed the Grub boot loader completely from my system. I might just get regular Ubuntu (; ^ _ ^ )

Comment: Good choice, glad it was helpful! If you do try vanilla Ubuntu, I would try the 17.10 beta to get GNOME.